# Why are my filesystem paths differing in local machine and when hosted on VPS?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have some storage operations being done in my controllers, this is the code that works on my local machine:

```
Storage::copy('public/filename.pdf', 'public/sub_directory/filename_'.$var.'.pdf');
Storage::delete('public/filename.pdf');
```

With this code, I am successfully able to copy a file in `laravel_root/storage/app/public/`, then copy and rename the file to `laravel_root/storage/app/public/subdirectory/`, the file in `public/` gets deleted after the copy operation. This works on my local machine.

When I pushed the code up to the staging server, above paths did not work and I got `ERROR: No such file or directory`.

I got this working by changing the paths from what worked on the local machine to :

```
Storage::copy('filename.pdf', 'subdirectory/filename_'.$var.'.pdf');
Storage::delete('job_card.pdf');
```

I had to remove out the `public/`from the operations.

My question is - Why does this differ in local machine and when pushed to server?

I am running on macOS on local Machine and ubuntu 16 on the staging server. I did not change any of the config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this has to do with your filesystems config.

Look in `config/filesystems.php` for the root of the disks.

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => 'your-key',
        'secret' => 'your-secret',
        'region' => 'your-region',
        'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
    ],

],
```

Local is `storage_path('app')` and public is `storage_path('app/public')`

Comment: Thanks! the `config/filesystem.php` was set to `'default' => 'local'` in my local machine and `'default' => 'public'` in my staging server

Comment: No problems. You can also specify the driver to use as well. eg. ```Storage::disk('local')->copy('public/filename.pdf', 'public/sub_directory/filename_'.$var.'.pdf');```. [more info](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem)